# Is it proper to say that something from someplace "is" someplace?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

I have heard many people say the following phrases:

> Is that Chipotle?
>   This McDonalds is so good.
>   Is that Gucci or Prada?

I was just wondering if these phrases are indeed proper, or should one rather say:

> Is that from Chipotle?
>   This McDonald's food is so good.
>   Is that Gucci or Prada merchandise?

Maybe both the case is such that both are in fact correct, or neither at that rate. Maybe I am not even considering all the possible cases, however I have been wondering for a long time what is the correct thing to say in a situation as such, thanks!

Comment: +1 A very interesting question @Xui -  I am a native English speaker, and this usage is so commonplace that I never noticed it until your question! Welcome to ELL. This will be of real value to others.

Comment: The brand name is used as an identifier. "Is this *Rolling Rock*? --No, it's *Yuengling*." (beers). "Is this *Ben & Jerry's*? -- No, it's *Edy's*". (ice cream). It would be a little odd, but not ungrammatical, to ask "Is this *Rolling Rock* beer?" We would say "Is this beer *Rolling Rock*?"  
or "Is this ice cream *Edy's*?"

Comment: I think this may be an example of [metonymy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/metonymy) - the food isn't literally "McDonald's", because McDonald's is a chain, but it's associated with McDonald's.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that (from) Chipotle?

Including *from* indicates the location or name of where you got the food. Without (from), you are just naming the food (Chipotle food).

> This McDonald's (food) is so good.
>   Is that Gucci or Prada (merchandise)?

In these, *food* and *merchandise* as implied information can be omitted, as long as it is understood in context what is meant.